# Closed form of geometric series

Tags: summation, summation-method

$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n ar^k =\cfrac{ar^{n+1}-a}{r-1} $

Is there a similar formula for

$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n ar^{k^2} $

Comment: @Arjun: That would give him a closed form for $\sum ar^{2k},$ which is different hrom what he asked.

Comment: @Bumblebee ah yes my bad

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum